# ubuntu Course my system generating heat

Tags: bash

Sometime, when I'm using my Ubuntu system and open vs code without running any command on terminal, the system will run by itself and show me this on the terminal:
This eroor is showing on the terminal
This error is showing without running anything

```
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `grep -E 'dircolors|lesspipe' ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_pofile ~/.profile 2>/dev/null`. Also, please clarify where exactly you see these messages (in the VS code terminal? In another terminal? What did you run in that terminal?) and what you mean by "heat" in the title.